# Star Wars holographic effect in GLSL / HLSL shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, direct3d, hlsl

Does anybody have any idea how to implement Star Wars like holographic effect in HLSL / GLSL ?

Comment: Not everyone has seen this, can you try to describe in more detail what you are looking for.

Comment: @James: I'd assume that [this](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20091007163905/starwars/images/thumb/e/e0/The_Ultimate_Weapon.jpg/830px-The_Ultimate_Weapon.jpg) is what is meant

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Funny how different this is [from what I thought](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/816/starwars2.jpg/)  :-)

Comment: @Damon: I guess the transition from red holograph emitters (Ep 1-3) to blue in Ep 4-6 (which are higher energy) might parallel red LED -> blue LED in the real world.  Or it might just be for coolness factor.

Comment: At the danger of going offtopic, in my opinion the new episodes (1-3) totally fail as far as coolness is concerned, anyway. They'd fit wonderfully into Startrek TNG alike, but not into a storyline where firing a superlaser takes 5 engineers half a minute of work, pushing 20 levers on a computer control the size of my bedroom (with many blinking lights, as every _real_ computer has!). The old movies were just so much more original... But, back on topic... I think if the modern "red" variant is desired, one would need to add some blooming too.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:
My answer refers to the "classic" blueish holonet appearance, rather than the more bloomy, reddish appearance in the more modern Episode 1-3 movies that Ben found on the internet (the question doesn't make clear which one is desired).
If the more modern red look is desired, one would have to use red instead of blue, obviously, and add a bloom effect for the "aura" (threshold/bright-pass, blur, add to image, see for example [here](http://kalogirou.net/2006/05/20/how-to-do-good-bloom-for-hdr-rendering/)).

(original answer)
That looks mostly like a semi-transparent, not too accurate, blueish "black and white" effect.

Thus, I'd calculate the luminance (something like `dot(color.xyz, vec3(0.67, 0.21, 0.14))` though uniform weight (0.333) will probably look ok too), and output that in the blue channel only, possibly adding some bias and multiplying some gain, to make it a little tweakable.

That, and enable alpha blending, and tweak it with the constant alpha as transparent as you like it.

Possibly one could add a bit of Perlin noise to the luminance too, to give it a bit "less accuracy" and more of a slightly "imperfect" appearance, like those holo thigies have in the movies.